# Show number of weeks in a given month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

So, I've been stuck on this problem for last couple of days and I still couldn't come up with solution.

I want to group given month into weeks which is fairly easy but the (horrible)business requirement is to consider a single day also as a week if it 
falls on any day between Monday to Sunday. The end day of the week is going to be Sunday.

For example I'll take month of August for demonstration. According to business requirement, this is how the data should be displayed for the given month

```
First week  - August 1st to August 2nd, 2015
Second week - August 3nd to August 9th, 2015
Third week  - August 10th to August 16th, 2015
Fourth week - August 17th to August 23rd, 2015
Fifth week  - August 24th to August 30th, 2015
Sixth week  - August 31st, 2015
```

I'm completely clueless on how to proceed with the problem due to the sixth week occurrence. 
I came across this query on AskTom which display 5 weeks but resets back to 1 on the 31st of August. Moreover, the query doesn't look like an elegant solution.

```
select dt, to_char( dt+1, 'w' )
     from ( select to_date('1-aug-2015')+rownum dt
              from all_objects
                    where rownum < 31 );
```

Looking for suggestions/insights on the problem. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH x (dt)
     AS (    SELECT DATE '2015-08-01' + LEVEL - 1 dt
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY DATE '2015-08-01' + LEVEL - 1 < DATE '2015-09-01')
SELECT dt,
       SUM (
          CASE
             WHEN TO_CHAR (dt, 'd') = '2'      --if the day is monday
               OR TO_CHAR (dt, 'fmdd') = '1'   --or if its the first day of the month, assign 1.
             THEN
                1
             ELSE
                0
          END)
       OVER (ORDER BY dt)
          wk_nr
  FROM x;
```

1. First generate all days for the given month.
2. Identify the beginning of each week and the start of the month by marking it as 1. Mark rest of the days as 0. Here to_char(dt,'d') gives 2 for monday. But may change based on NLS territory of the session.
3. Now that you have beginning of each week, use SUM to calculate the cumulative sum. This gives you the desired week number.

Sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/30358).

---

***UPDATE***

Looks like 10g doesn't support [column alias](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_103a.htm#2065648) with the CTE name. Remove it and try.

```
WITH x 
     AS (SELECT ....
```

Comment: Great solution! This is what I was looking for. Fiddle display the desired result however I can't seem to run it on 10G release. It throws `ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing` error at line 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
   --TRY THIS
```

--I DID IT FOR SYSDATE.

```
   SELECT DT,
   CASE
       WHEN TO_CHAR(DT+1, 'W')='1'
            AND SUBSTR(DT,1,2)>'24' THEN '6'
       ELSE TO_CHAR(DT+1, 'W')
   END
   FROM
    (SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE)+ROWNUM DT FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
     );
```

--THE QUERY IN YOUR EXAMPLE.

```
  SELECT DT,CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( DT+1, 'w' )='1' AND SUBSTR( DT,1,2)>'24' THEN '6' ELSE    TO_CHAR( DT+1, 'w' ) END
 from ( select to_date('1-aug-2015')+rownum dt
        FROM ALL_OBJECTS
        WHERE ROWNUM < 31
      );
```

Comment: The second query works fine +1 to you for that, but like I said I really don't want to resort to this query as an accepted solution. Thanks though. I will wait till I get more sophisticated query as solution.

Comment: I think this is the best approach or else you may have to use some analytical functions

Comment: Which is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this work for other months? Looks like it works for this month only.

Answer (score -2):

A table variable works really well:

```
declare @calendar table (WkDay date, DayOfWk int, YR INT, MO INT)
DECLARE @BEG_DT DATE
SET @BEG_DT='2016-12-01'
WHILE @BEG_DT <='2250-01-01'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @calendar VALUES (@BEG_DT, DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@BEG_DT), DATEPART(YEAR,@BEG_DT), DATEPART(MONTH,@BEG_DT))

    SET @BEG_DT=DATEADD(DAY,1,@BEG_DT)
END

SELECT *
FROM @calendar
```

then count the number of "1" dayofwk and you get the number of weeks in a given month